# Does gwt have i18n support for distance format?

Tags: gwt, internationalization

Distance format like number, currency and datetime format for km, mi, yard, etc.

Answer (score 0):

here's a link to a tutorial

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/i18n

and more

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n

but since gwt is based on java, and according to [stackoverflow.com/questions/7659952/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659952/internationalization-of-distances-in-java)… ... java doesn't contain any distance internationalization...so i dont think it has

Comment: Could you point me to exact class for distance format. 

I know and I am using number, currency and datetime format i18n gwt support but I don't what class am I supposed to use?

Comment: You do realize that I have i18n experience and that before I posted here question I looked at documentation and tried to find answer with Google. I don't need tutorial for i18n of strings, number or datetime format. 

I need to know does gwt have i18n support for distance format. I don't need conversion but I would like to know what distance symbol to use for some local. 

Do you have experience with i18n of distance in gwt?

Comment: since gwt is based on java, and  according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659952/internationalization-of-distances-in-java ... java doesn't contain any distance internationalization...so i dont think it has

Comment: Now we are on same page. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Units of Measurement API](https://code.google.com/p/unitsofmeasure/) respectively its implementations in the [JScience](http://jscience.org/) library. However I don't know whether the library can be compiled using the GWT JS compiler...